# Prestashop 1.6.0.13 remove Header phone

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Prestashop 1.6.0.13, How can I remove the Header phone?

in:
     /themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcontact/nav.tpl

At the end appear this lines:

```
 {if $telnumber} <span class="shop-phone"> <i class="icon-phone"></i>{l s='Call us now:' mod='blockcontact'} <strong>{$telnumber}</strong> </span> {/if}
```

---

And I changed it for that:

{* {if $telnumber}  {l s='Call us now:' mod='blockcontact'} **{$telnumber}**  {/if} *}

But still appears the head phone

I tried removing the lines and also apperas the header phone.

---

I have made a capture/photo of "inspect this element" of the Header contact phone (and work time for phone) that appears in the header and is what I want to remove:

The photo is https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcxktazzjzkzrxa/help.jpg?dl=0

I hope you can help me to discover the line in the tpl file of prestashop to remove this: 
1) the phone icon 
2)the words "Días laborales de 11h a 13h"
3) the phone number (34) 676....

Comment: what do you mean by "header phone"? 
do you mean phone icon?

Comment: I mean the first line of the header field  of Prestashop

Comment: icon phone and also the line with the number phone.

Comment: Each site is slightly different and its hard to say without any image but I think you are close just press f12 inspect this element and try to find it around this line which you commented out, that stuff which you commented out is just for number nothing more you need to find tags which are wrapping it and comment them out as well

Comment: I have made a capture/photo of "inspect this element" of the Header contact phone (and work time for phone)  that appears in the header and is what I want to remove but still keeping all the other stuff. I wonder how to upload it (one second I am uploading it in dropbox) I hope you can help me to discover the line in the tpl file of prestashop to remove info contact of header

Comment: The photo https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcxktazzjzkzrxa/help.jpg?dl=0   Now, how can I remove (in prestashop file) this: 
1) the phone icon 
2)the words "Días laborales de 11h a 13h"
3) the phone number (34) 676....

Comment: so you will need to remove whole tag starting <span class="shop-phone"> if that's not in this template file you will need to find the right template are you using default-bootstrap template?

Comment: In this file: 
/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcontact/nav.tpl 
this code:

{if $telnumber}
 <span class="shop-phone">
  <i class="icon-phone"></i>{l s='Call us now:' mod='blockcontact'} <strong>{$telnumber}</strong>
 </span>
{/if}
_________________________________________
I must to convert into this?

{if $telnumber}
{/if}

sure? or what?

Comment: if this template is used you can just remove whole this line starting from {if $telnumber} up to the {/if} and clear the cache if is enabled and that should do

Comment: I clear all the line code since  {if $telnumber} until {/if}, also clear cache, but doesn't work. I upload the image of the tpl file, can you help me please? https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4n4mnfwgazs4m8/prestashop%20navtpl.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Thanks. I fix it deleting all the "contact"  button,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling for several days for the same reason.

You just have to access the backend, then go to **Advanced Parameters->Performance** and select the second option: "**Recompile templates when files are modified**".
(Please note I've translated from my Spanish backend so some words may differ).

Then just **Save** and reload your site.

Hope it helps!